# strcat not prepending strings in C

Tags: c, string, prepend, strcat

I'm working on an apache module that converts groups of slashes into single slashes in order to avoid duplicate content on a website. The problem I have is that the strcat functions don't seem to be doing anything. I'm trying to use them to prepend "http://example.com" to the resulting URL for a user to redirect to if it initially contained groups of 2 or more slashes stuck together.

```
static int handler(request_rec *r){
    if (strcmp(r->handler,"httpd/unix-directory")==0){return DECLINED;}
    unsigned long flag=0,ct=0;
    char xi[100004],*xuri=xi,*up=r->unparsed_uri;
    *xuri='\0';
    strcat(xuri,"http://");
    strcat(xuri,r->hostname);
    while (*up != '\0'){
        if (*up=='/'){flag++;}else{flag=0;}
        if (flag < 2){*xuri=*up;xuri++;ct++;if (ct >= 100000){break;}}
        if (flag > 1){flag=2;}
        up++;
    }
    if (ct < 100000){
        if (ct > 0){xuri--;}
        if (*xuri=='/'){*xuri='\0';}
        xuri++;*xuri='\0';
        xuri=xi;up=r->unparsed_uri;
        if (strcmp(up,xuri)==0){return DECLINED;} //no redirect for same URL
        r->content_type = "text/html";
        apr_table_set(r->headers_out,"Location",xuri);
        return HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY;
    }else{
        return HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
}
```

Currently the tail of any URL (for example, the /123 part from http://example.com/123) is read and only the tail is outputted, but I want the http://example.com/ part prepended.

What can I do to get strcat to work in my favor?

Comment: I'm sure the `strcat` function works just fine, but you do something else that make you think it doesn't. Try running in a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see what *really* happens (but then I suggest you add more line-breaks which incidentally will make your code more readable).

Comment: Please help us out a bit by telling us where in the code you are checking the strcat output and determining that it is wrong. AFAICS your code changes `xuri` after `strcat` has done its job. So how have you determined that it is `strcat` that is not working (which I doubt) and not your subsequent code that mucks up the buffer?

Comment: maybe strcat really doesn't advance the xuri pointer? I thought it did? In my while loop, xuri only advances when a value is set to it in the current position.

Comment: @Mike: How can `strcat` possibly advance a pointer that is passed to `strcat` *by value*??? `strcat` wouln't be able to advance it even if it wanted to. The implementation of `strcat` has no access to `xuri`. It can only access a copy of `xuri`.

Comment: I thought at first it would because if one issued multiple strcat statements, you would think data gets added to the string and then I thought maybe the pointer is updated each time data is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat` doesn't update `xuri`. So `xuri` is still pointing to the beginning of the string after the two calls to `strcat`. So when the code reaches the statements `*xuri=*up;xuri++;`, it's overwriting the string starting from the beginning.

You can fix the problem by using `sprintf` instead, since that allows you to update `xuri` appropriately, e.g. replace these three lines

```
*xuri='\0';
strcat(xuri,"http://");
strcat(xuri,r->hostname);
```

with this line

```
xuri += sprintf( "http://%s", r->hostname );
```